# Load more button not moving after appending new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK I have been meaning to ask this question. I have the load more div inserted in my html body tag:

```
<a href="#" class="load-more">Load More...</a>
```

Each time I refresh my page, the Load more... text appears fist before the content is loaded which I didn't like. So I thought of taking advantage of the append function by adding it like this:

```
$("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh').append('<a class="load-more">Load more...</a>');
```

This seems to do the trick since it doesn't show up on page refresh first but the challenge I have with this is that when new contents are added, the Load more text does not move to end of page but rather remains at the initial position it was when it first appeared. How can I work around this or is there a better method to use:

[image]

Load More Code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".load-more", function() {
    $.getJSON("url", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        var rtitle = $('<p/>', {'class' : 'vtitle', html: val.title}),
            rexcerpt = $('<p/>', {'class': 'vexcept', html: val.excerpt});
            var rappend = $('<li/>').append(rtitle, rexcerpt);
            $('#postlist').append(rappend);
            $('#postlist').listview().listview('refresh');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: without code that adds more content...not easy for anyone to assist you. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Will need to move that `load more` within your insertion code. Or change it's css position perhaps to absolute

Comment: Why is that buttons supposed to move? is there some code that moves it? Or is the newly loaded content appended to some element of the DOM that is before the "load more" button? or at least inserted before the "load more" button in the same parent element? If neither, there is no reason why it should move.

Comment: I have included the Load more code. The bit that appends the Load more text is a diff function

Answer (score 0):

you can set parent tag `position:relative;` and load more `position:absolute;` then work with `bottom` and `left`, like this:

[**jsFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/w9mqD/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a>load more...</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    background:tomato;
}

a{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    background:#eee;
}
```